# Where can I get a list of macros beginning with \var

Tags: macros

I use macros like `\varphi` or `\vartheta` quite often, and I've recently discovered, there is also a `\varnothing` which is a bit like the `\emptyset`.

My question is: How or where can I get a list of symbols beginning with `\var*`

And in general, is there a way, I can get XeLaTeX print out commands that are defined?

Comment: Why not grep the sources?  The problem then (more or less) reduces to knowing which are primitives and which are defined - but this is easily solvable with The TeXbook.  (Of course, some formats might redefine things - both primitives and macros, e.g. `\input` - but then, `source2e.pdf` to the rescue!)

Comment: It's not possible to dump the commands that are defined, at least from within TeX; the only way is do a memory dump and look at it (I wouldn't try myself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on used classes and packages. If you are interested on possibilities, *The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List*  http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/ should be a good starter. In the index you have about one hundred names starting with `\var`.

Comment: hmm, this is what I've pretty much came up with also. I though there might be a LaTeX command, that would allow me to print such variables, etc. Kinda like it's possible in Matlab, etc...

Comment: OK, I've tried many things suggested in here, and searching the document is the best option (with a good viewer, like evince).

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Searching for `var` on all files used by TeXstudio for autocompletion I found [this list](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7439986/) (note that not all of them begins with `var`):